# API call to sugar crm

Tags: api, rest, sugarcrm

I have to make a call to some data in SugarCRM using OAuth in REST API.
I am using this [link](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Authentication/Oauth/index.html)

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you want data from another module then , call a api in js controller like this.

```
app.api.call('GET', app.api.buildURL('Accounts/' + this.model.attributes.accounts_lab_coc_1accounts_ida), null, {
            success: _.bind(function (response) {
                //response comes back from your api, maybe you want to set some value on your model or alter a response?
                console.log(response);


                    }
                }, this);

            }, this)
        });

    },
```

Comment: i am trying to fetch the data using rest api in sugarcrm online but i am not getting any any response